# Newspaper Action DB integration?

Tags: wordpress, extension

Has anyone integrated a newspaper action page (e.g., site visitor puts in zip code and page shows local, regional, statewide options for writing a letter to the editor)? If so, where might one get access to a portion of that database for a specific state? Thanks!

We are using CiviCRM with WordPress.

Answer (score 1):

No I haven't done so. But in Drupal this is possible with the views module. CiviCRM has a great integration with the views module and you could create a view which shows all news within the region of the logged in civicrm contact.

What I would do is to create a custom set with all the regions. This could be custom contacts in civi with a relationship, or a custom select list on the contact card and probably with some coding you could set this field automaticly or let the user select in which region he lives. And this select list you also use at your news artivles to link them to regions.

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned we are using Wordpress. Thanks for responding!

Comment: I am not really familiar with Wordpress but I thought wordpress has a simialir solution but I ma not sure how it is called.